# Accessing object data with forEach, without the use of forEach's thisArg?

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, undefined, this

I'm reading through http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/ and trying to get a better understanding of "this".

However I ran into something that is confusing me: I can't seem to access object data (in this case of the "user" object) without using forEach's "this" argument.

http://jsfiddle.net/t7fvj0zp/

I can get the info this way:

```
var user = {
    tournament:"The Masters",
    data :[
    {name:"T. Woods", age:37},
    {name:"P. Mickelson", age:43}
    ],

    clickHandler:function () {            
        this.data.forEach (function (person) {
            console.log (person.name);
        })
    }
}

user.clickHandler(); //"T. Woods", "P. Mickelson"
```

However, below brings up "undefined":

```
console.log (user.data.name);
```

Or this brings up "this.user is undefined":

```
console.log (this.user.data.name);
```

What am I missing? Is it not possible to "backtrack" and, within forEach, access object info without the use of thisArg? Or perhaps, what is the equivalent to "person" written longwise?

Comment: `user.data` is an array. Try `console.log(user.data[0].name);` instead

Comment: @friedi Thanks, that did work. However, since it is a forEach loop, is there a way to have it print off both names? Or is that where thisArg becomes necessary, or a "for" loop within the forEach loop? EDIT: Okay, tantalum said "no" below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN's forEach documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach):

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach`, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value. Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its this value.

So no it is not possible to "backtrack" and access the object info without using `thisArg`.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that but didn't fully understand what that meant.

Answer (score 1):

data is an array of object, not an associative array,
so try something like :

```
console.log (user.data[0].name);
```

or

```
console.log (this.user.data[0].name);
```

to acess your data.

and you need to pass a parameter to forEach to aceess the value like this

```
   clickHandler:function () {            
        this.data.forEach (function (value) {
            console.log (value.name);
        })
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t7fvj0zp/1/

Hope i help